# How to cache image to document folder with file name from url

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to cache image into Caches folder with file name. I have a collection view load images url from internet. So i want cache images with file name as url in Caches folder. Thank in advance

Comment: You could use the SHA-1 hash of the image URL to create the filename (you would probably want to force all characters of the URL to lowercase as part of the process).  This would always create a valid filename, regardless of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the image and saving it to the Caches folder is very easy:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    NSString *urlString = @"http://URL";

     NSData *webData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    if (webData) {
        // save in the Filesystem
        NSString* cachesDirectory =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *file = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[urlString lastPathComponent]];
        [webData writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
    }
});
```

But when you display images ios uses lazy image decompression, which produces a delay on main thread. To avoid these delays there are great libraries:

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

[FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache)

I would recommend you to use one of these.

Comment: I would strongly recommend SDWebImage. It is the best.